# SharePoint 2010 and VS 2010 - which releases work well?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I'm having a hard time finding a combination of sharepoint and vs releases that work well together.  So far I have tried:

SP 4730 & VS RTM
SP 4747 & VS RC 
SP 4763 (Debug RTM ish) & VS RC

All of these had issues in one or both products.  I'm now reverting to SP 4747 & VS RTM.  Has anyone else found a combo that works well?

Specifically, I'm creating a service application with some sync framework goodness. I get errors when deploying from vs or running the powershell cmdlets to deploy and provision stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that RTM of both works best :)

Comment: Stupid question, what is RTM?